# Get File Timestamp from Dropbox

Tags: c#, dropbox-api

I have the following code:

```
        private static void Download(DropboxClient client, string dropboxfolder, string localfolder, FileMetadata file)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("Download file...");
            var task1 = client.Files.DownloadAsync(dropboxfolder + "/" + file.Name);
            task1.Wait();
            using (var response = task1.Result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Downloaded {0} Rev {1}", response.Response.Name, response.Response.Rev);
                Console.WriteLine("------------------------------");
                using (Stream output = File.OpenWrite(Path.Combine(localfolder, response.Response.Name)))
                {
                    var task2 = response.GetContentAsStreamAsync();
                    task2.Wait();
                    using (Stream input = task2.Result)
                    {
                        input.CopyTo(output);
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine("------------------------------");
            }
        }
```

how do I modify it such that the `output` file will have the same timestamp as the file in dropbox.

[EDIT]  I know how to set a date of a file in C#, but I don't know how to get that timestamp from dropbox in order to call that method.  The question I am asking is more generic than that because perhaps there is an option on the dropbox API that allows the file to be set by dropbox.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.setcreationtime?view=net-6.0

Comment: you may need find some mothod in `DropboxClient` to get the timestamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use [`DownloadAsync`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/html/M_Dropbox_Api_Files_Routes_FilesUserRoutes_DownloadAsync_1.htm) to download a file, that also returns the [`FileMetadata`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/html/T_Dropbox_Api_Files_FileMetadata.htm) for that file. You can check the [`FileMetadata.ServerModified`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/html/P_Dropbox_Api_Files_FileMetadata_ServerModified.htm) or [`FileMetadata.ClientModified`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/html/P_Dropbox_Api_Files_FileMetadata_ClientModified.htm) to get the modified time as desired.

You can find [an example of getting the metadata here](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/blob/b5dff871d353c46dcdf61f0319a10be4ed0b8c0c/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/Examples/SimpleBlogDemo/Helpers/BlogHelpers.cs#L51).